# Calculate the annual use of a service starting from the date of signing

Tags: c#, mysql, date, datetime

I need to calculate the annual use of a service starting from the date of signing. Something like:

```
select Count(*) from TABLENAME where Date >= MYDATE
```

`MYDATE` need to be calculate from a subscription date and I need to get the last year date from subscription referring to the current date

Some examples:

> subscription date: 2007-06-29
>
> if current date is : 2015-04-29 then date is: 2014-06-29
>
> if current date is : 2015-06-29 then date is: 2015-06-29
>
> if current date is : 2015-06-29 then date is: 2015-06-29

I'm using c# to calculate the date but it crashes in leapyear:

```
var date = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, subscriptionDate.Month, subscriptionDate.Day);
if (DateTime.Now.Date < date)
{
    date = date.AddYears(-1);
}
```

**I was wondering if there were a clever/better way to do it in c# or mysql also handling leapyear**

---UPDATE----

[Running example with suggested solutions](http://goo.gl/uF8KJP)

Comment: What would you do if they subscribed on Feb 29th 2012?

Comment: Also, "I need to get the last year date from subscription referring to the current date" isn't clear to me... it would really help if you would give some examples of what you're trying to do.

Comment: @JonSkeet good point about 29 Feb. I know I'm not clear. sorry for my bad english i'll add some example

Comment: @JonSkeet added examples

Comment: Why you don't discount 365 days? Or 366? Then you avoid having false days like 29th February 2013

Comment: What if the current date is 2015-06-29?

Comment: @JonSkeet then date is  2015-06-29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I'd do it in [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org), myself:

```
LocalDate subscriptionDate = ...;
LocalDate today = ...; // Need to take time zone into account
int years = Period.Between(subscriptionDate, today);
return subscription.PlusYears(years);
```

With .NET that would be slightly harder, but I'd still go for the approach of adding years (and letting it do the truncation for Feb 29th):

```
// Only call this *once* - otherwise you could get inconsistent results
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
int years = today.Year - subscriptionDate.Year;
DateTime candidate = subscriptionDate.AddYears(years);
// We might have overshot, in which case lower the number of years.
return candidate <= today ? candidate : subscriptionDate.AddYears(years - 1);
```

Comment: did not know about Noda time. Nice library. Thanks for your suggestions, maybe I found a simpler solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28484111/921690  what do you think?

Comment: This all reminds me to your (@JonSkeet 's ) talk about data types and their inconsistencies :-)

Comment: @giammin: Your edit was incorrect, as we're adding years to `subscriptionDate`, not to `candidate`. We don't want to add years to `candidate` as that's potentially already "slightly off" for leap years. (We don't want to truncate from Feb 29th to Feb 28th for a non-leap year, then keep it as Feb 28th when going back to a leap year.)

Comment: i created a test with all the suggested solution http://goo.gl/uF8KJP yours works as expected!

Answer (score 0):

Use mysql `DATE_SUB` function

```
DATE_SUB(Date, INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Yuri Dorokhov answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28483496/921690) and [Jon Skeet suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28483049/get-last-year-from-a-given-date#comment45288166_28483049)

I found a solution that works well and handle leap year:

```
int year = DateTime.Now.DayOfYear >= subscriptionDate.DayOfYear ? 
             DateTime.Now.Year : DateTime.Now.Year - 1;
var date = new DateTime(year, 1, 1).AddDays(subscriptionDate.DayOfYear - 1);
```

--------UPDATE------

**I leave here this answer as reference but it does not handle well leap year so don't use it**

Comment: Firstly, you're still calling `DateTime.Now` multiple times - it's possible that the clock will tick over from one year to the next between calls. Don't do that. Secondly, that doesn't give you the result you wanted - if the original value is after Feb 29th in a leap year, for example, the result in *non*-leap years will be one day later than it should be, e.g. March 6th instead of March 5th. Basically, I'd personally stick to my solution - I view it as simpler.

Comment: @JonSkeet i know about `DateTime.Now` and how to correctly handle date with timezone info. The code I wrote in question and answer is simplified just for read readability. I have to calculate the annual use of a service starting from the date of signing. and if is legit if someone subscribed 29 feb to use 1 march instead of 28 feb to calculate annual use

Comment: But it's not just that situation - it's *everyone* who subscribes after Feb 29th in a leap year - their subscription will run a day later in every non-leap year. Suppose you change your example to be 2008 instead of 2007 - that shouldn't change the results, right? But with your code, it will.

Comment: @JonSkeet I get your point, you are right. your solution is the one which fit better my requirement, thanks